# Completion block not called (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I have written a function with a completion block as an argument. When I call this function in my view controller, the completion block is not executed. This is my first time writing my own custom completion block, so I may be making just an easy mistake. Here is the function in my model:

```
func iterateThrough2(userInput: String, completion: (completed: Bool) -> Bool) -> Double {

    while numberOfCharactersDone < userInput.characters.count {
        let startIndex = userInput.startIndex.advancedBy(numberOfCharactersDone)
        let letterIndex = userInput.characters[startIndex]
        let letter = String(letterIndex)
        if isLetter(letter) {
            isALetter(letter, input: userInput)
        }
        else {
            isNotLetter(letter)
        }
        numberOfCharactersDone++
    }
    return total
}
```

And in my view controller, I call it:

```
@IBAction func calculate(sender: UIButton) {
    if let text = self.enteredText.text {
       let result = calculator.iterateThrough2(text, completion: { (completed) -> Bool in
        if completed {
            print("good")
            return true
        }
        else {
            print("not good")
            return false
        }
       })
        self.outputLabel.text = String(result)
        calculator.resetData()
    }
  }
```

The function does successfully return a double, as it should, and it is working otherwise. It just doesn't call the closure. What am I doing wrong?

Do I have to include and specify in my method when exactly I want the closure to be ran? I read here: https://www.codefellows.org/blog/writing-completion-blocks-with-closures-in-swift and tried to call the completion block at the end of my method like:

```
completion(completed: completed)
return total
```

but I got an error "use of unresolved identifier "completed""

Comment: You have to call it like -> completion(true) or completion(false), got it?

Comment: yes indeed that was it, thanks!